# How export constant keys?

Tags: animation, export, import, keyframes

I have recorder cutscene where the characters and the camera are teleported depending on the camera frame using constant keys.
When exporting to unity, the keys become linear and the movement between teleportation becomes noticeable, how do I solve this? (Simplify doesn't help)

To reproduce the problem, you need to record the constant key, export fbx, import it, and it will become linear (in the span of one frame).

[image]

baked : [image]

Answer (score 1):

If when exporting your asset you let the bake animation enabled and the sampling rate on 1, then it should put keys on each frame of your animations, removing any interpolation and negating the effects of key type change.

I forgot to mention, Blender's FBX exporter does a keyframe cleanup in its baking, which you might want to remove by setting the "simplify" to 0.

Comment: It always export linear keyframes, i need contant

Comment: You won't export constant keyframes, hence the baking. If you bake the animation on export, it will place keyframes everywhere needed so that you don't leave any of your animation to hazardous interpolations and incompatible data transfers. Plus in videogame you want your animations to be baked so you don't use extra resources calculating unnecessary interpolations, it's faster to have as much keyframes as you can bear. I forgot to mention, Blender's FBX exporter does a keyframe cleanup in its baking, which you might want to remove by setting the "simplify" to 0.

Comment: I cant export fbx animation without baking. So its impossible?

Comment: You can't export any other keyframe type but linear. You have to bake if you have animation data that can't be done using only linear (which is basically every animation in the world) and you have to bake for performance and data reliability anyway. So, just always bake, out of principle.

Comment: So, how can i make teleports in cutscene like this? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXW5Z1fmlb0

Unity shows the movement between frames well, do I need to limit the frames in unity or increase them in blender?

Comment: Have you baked your animation with the settings I advised you?

Comment: yep, still can notice movement in unity between blender frames

Comment: Then post your files he so we can check this. It's not normal.