# Animation broken importing exporting FBX Blender

Tags: animation

I have had a problem for two months and I can't find a solution. I created a 3d model and I would like to animate it easily so I used mixamo which provides animations from a template that you upload. And I would like to have my 3d model and all my animations in a single FBX. But when I export from Blender for the Idle animation the feet of my model levitate. Attached is the Idle animation generated by mixamo so far so good but if you import it into Blender and export it your feet will float.

PS: Animation work well in Blender

Idle.fbx: https://we.tl/t-c6EwB40jDb

If someone could confirm my problem I would be very grateful

EDIT: here is a video of my problem: https://youtu.be/NUKfyS4T_yg

Comment: One helpful thing you can do, is to share/attach a screenshot of this Levitation you speak of, because having imported the .FBX file to blender, and exported to maximo as well, I didnt see a Levitation, except you are viewing the character from a low or bottom angle/view.

Comment: You right I recorded a video of what I get. I'm curious how you did it? https://youtu.be/NUKfyS4T_yg

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by setting Simplify to 0 in Bake Animation when exporting as FBX

[How export constant keys?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218052/how-export-constant-keys)
[What does the "simplify" option when exporting to FBX?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239254/what-does-the-simplify-option-when-exporting-to-fbx)